# Apache Hadoop-connection refused to localhost when submitting job in spark-cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, connection, localhost

i am trying to setup apache spark and hadoop. However when trying to submit a spark cluster job, i am getting the following error " connection refused to localhost:54310". I am quite new to this. Can anyone help me by telling me how to setup the correct hadoop port/hostname that the client is trying to use  and submit the spark cluster correctly? many thanks

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to submit your job ? What is the URL of your master (of type `spark://..:7077`) ?

Comment: i use spark-submit --class Simple --master spark://localhost:7077 hdfs://localhost:54310/pathtothejarfile.jar

Comment: Can you check on the master web UI or in the log file created when launching `start-master` what is the exact `spark://...` URL ? Mine doesn't work with localhost, I need to give my qualified hostname.

Comment: I have tried with the actual localhost too, and i also tried by adding deploy mode --cluster command. Still does not work. I actually want to know how hadoop is connected to apache spark via localhost and how to specify the correct port for the client to use!!

Comment: Sorry, I misread your problem. Spark isn't really connected to Hadoop, it uses parts of Hadoop internally to run but can run totally on its own. What you are trying to achieve is to access the HDFS. Did you start your Hadoop cluster correctly (formatted the namenode and used `start-dfs.sh`) ? You can refer to [this documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution) if you are using the latest Hadoop version. The port that is used by default by HDFS is `9000`.

Comment: Thank you. yes i started hadoop using ./start-dfs.sh. and did see the namenode , datanode , secondarynamenode starting up. After that i went to the spark directory and ran the spark-submit command. Does ur comment mean that in my core-site.xml file, I will have to change it to hfs://localhost:9000? and is my command correct?

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using ? What do you already have in your `core-site.xml` ?

Comment: 2.6.4. <configuration>
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
 <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
 
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: I have `fs.defaultFS` as the property name, are you sure you have the correct syntax ?

Comment: I have tried changing and re run it. Nothign works. Any idea if my spark-submit is right?

Comment: Your `spark-submit` is right, even though there is no need to put your `jar` file on HDFS. You can simply give a relative path.  Are you using Spark's bundled Hadoop or Spark without Hadoop and a local installation of Hadoop aside ?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to load my file fro HDFS. Hence why that jar file. And I downloaded spark-bundled hadoop. And I have a local installation of hadoop 2.6.4 as well. Is there something about this that I should be careful about.As in will that make a difference why I am unable to load my file properly and submit my spark-command?

Comment: It all depends which Spark package you chose from [here](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). You might want to give [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version) page a read as well.